# Replace cell value according to bin value in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

First I would like to state that I cannot use pandas. What I'm trying to do is replace cell's value of a dataframe when the cell's value matches a particular value previously determined. Otherwise, leave the cell's value to be what it originally was.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    predictions = crossval.fit(trainingData).transform(trainingData)
    bins = predictions.select("prediction").distinct().collect()
    for row in bins:
        rows = predictions.select(["features", "prediction"]).filter(predictions.prediction == row.prediction).withColumnRenamed("prediction", "prediction_1")
        dt_model = dt.fit(rows)
        dt_transform = dt_model.transform(testData).select("prediction")
        predictions = predictions.withColumn("prediction", when(predictions.prediction == rows.prediction_1, dt_transform.prediction).otherwise(predictions.prediction))
```

The line that is giving me trouble is:

```
predictions = predictions.withColumn("prediction", when(predictions.prediction == rows.prediction_1, dt_transform.prediction).otherwise(predictions.prediction))
```

The error it is giving me is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "part2.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "part2.py", line 108, in main
    predictions = predictions.withColumn("prediction", when(predictions.prediction == rows.prediction_1, dt_transform.prediction).otherwise(predictions.prediction))
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1990, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Resolved attribute(s) prediction#3065,prediction_1#2949 missing from features#200,trip_duration#20,prediction#2925 in operator !Project [features#200, trip_duration#20, CASE WHEN (prediction#2925 = prediction_1#2949) THEN prediction#3065 ELSE prediction#2925 END AS prediction#3070]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: prediction. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;;\n!Project [features#200, trip_duration#20, CASE WHEN (prediction#2925 = prediction_1#2949) THEN prediction#3065 ELSE prediction#2925 END AS prediction#3070]\n+- Project [features#200, trip_duration#20, UDF(features#200) AS prediction#2925]\n   +- Sample 0.0, 0.8, false, 3709578444707833222\n      +- Sort [features#200 ASC NULLS FIRST, trip_duration#20 ASC NULLS FIRST], false\n         +- Project [features#200, trip_duration#20]\n            +- Project [vendor_id#11, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#178, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, day#117, hour#128, minute#140, second#153, UDF(named_struct(vendor_id_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(vendor_id#11 as double), passenger_count_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(passenger_count#14 as double), store_and_fwd_flag_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(store_and_fwd_flag#178 as double), distance_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(distance#33 as double), year_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(year#98 as double), month_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(month#107 as double), day_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(day#117 as double), hour_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(hour#128 as double), minute_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(minute#140 as double), second_double_VectorAssembler_42efd84316ac, cast(second#153 as double))) AS features#200]\n               +- Project [vendor_id#11, passenger_count#14, <lambda>(store_and_fwd_flag#19) AS store_and_fwd_flag#178, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, day#117, hour#128, minute#140, second#153]\n                  +- Project [vendor_id#11, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, day#117, hour#128, minute#140, second#153]\n                     +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, day#117, hour#128, minute#140, <lambda>(pickup_datetime#12) AS second#153]\n                        +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, day#117, hour#128, <lambda>(pickup_datetime#12) AS minute#140]\n                           +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, day#117, <lambda>(pickup_datetime#12) AS hour#128]\n                              +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, month#107, <lambda>(pickup_datetime#12) AS day#117]\n                                 +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, year#98, <lambda>(pickup_datetime#12) AS month#107]\n                                    +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33, <lambda>(pickup_datetime#12) AS year#98]\n                                       +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33]\n                                          +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, dropoff_datetime#13, passenger_count#14, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33]\n                                             +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, dropoff_datetime#13, passenger_count#14, dropoff_latitude#18, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33]\n                                                +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, dropoff_datetime#13, passenger_count#14, dropoff_longitude#17, dropoff_latitude#18, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33]\n                                                   +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, dropoff_datetime#13, passenger_count#14, pickup_latitude#16, dropoff_longitude#17, dropoff_latitude#18, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33]\n                                                      +- Project [vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, dropoff_datetime#13, passenger_count#14, pickup_longitude#15, pickup_latitude#16, dropoff_longitude#17, dropoff_latitude#18, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, distance#33]\n                                                         +- Project [id#10, vendor_id#11, pickup_datetime#12, dropoff_datetime#13, passenger_count#14, pickup_longitude#15, pickup_latitude#16, dropoff_longitude#17, dropoff_latitude#18, store_and_fwd_flag#19, trip_duration#20, <lambda>(pickup_longitude#15, pickup_latitude#16, dropoff_longitude#17, dropoff_latitude#18) AS distance#33]\n                                                            +- Relation[id#10,vendor_id#11,pickup_datetime#12,dropoff_datetime#13,passenger_count#14,pickup_longitude#15,pickup_latitude#16,dropoff_longitude#17,dropoff_latitude#18,store_and_fwd_flag#19,trip_duration#20] csv\n'
```

So far what I have realized is that I replace rows.prediction_1 and dt_transform.prediction with predictions.prediction, then it works. Just not like it's supposed to. So something is wrong with those two dataframes.

The output of predictions.show() is:

```
+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
|            features|trip_duration|        prediction|
+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|            8| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.02...|            9| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,0.0,0.0,15.1...|         2251|2659.7614115841966|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           37| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|         1084| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|          570| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|          599| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           21| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|            6| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           19| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|          177| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           44| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           35| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           60| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           79| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           73| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|          705| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|          580| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|           67| 299.6655053883315|
|[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,...|          640| 299.6655053883315|
+--------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: First, change .withColumn("prediction",...) to .withColumn("new_prediction",...). Second, change predictions.prediction inside the when and otherwise statement to col("prediction"). If it still doesn't work, print predictions.show() in your next edit, it will be helpful if we can see how it looks like.

Comment: @QuantStats I made the changes as you suggested. It still didn't work. I added the output of show to the original post. Currently, predictions looks like this:

predictions = predictions.withColumn("new_prediction", when(col("prediction") == rows["prediction_1"], dt_transform.prediction).otherwise(col("prediction")))

Comment: @QuantStats this seems to be some kind of bug with spark itself. I looked through what everyone's various solutions were but nothing pertaining to what I'm doing specifically. Do you think it's possible to have a workaround?

Comment: I will investigate and have a look in details later. Your idea is to do a two-stage estimation, yes? In the first stage - perform an estimation on the whole dataset to obtain first-stage predictions. In the second stage - perform a groupby (first-stage prediction values) estimation, then update the first-stage predictions with the second-stage predictions if they change. Did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark 1: `dt_transform = dt_model.transform(testData).select("prediction")` doesn't make much sense, due to a mismatch of *testData* and *rows* number of rows. You wouldn't be able to reassign *testData* new predictions back to *rows* predictions in the following line with `when` function because it operates row by row. A `join` function would have been a better choice.

Remark 2: `predictions = predictions.withColumn("prediction", when(predictions.prediction == rows.prediction_1, dt_transform.prediction).otherwise(predictions.prediction))` is illegal. For that operation, you can't have more than one data frame (you had three - *predictions*, *rows*, *dt_transform*). If you want to take or compare values in other data frames, you can use the `join` function.

Here is a short example I created to guide you with your two-stage estimation method.

> Stage 1 - run an estimation on the whole data to get preliminary predictions.
>
> Stage 2 - organize the data into subgroups (group by preliminary predictions), re-estimate, and update predictions.

Note: I am demonstrating using classification, however, my example can be adapted for your regression case.

Code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, DoubleType
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#create a sample data frame
data = [(1.54,3.45,2.56),(9.39,8.31,1.34),(1.25,3.31,9.87),(9.35,5.67,2.49),\
        (1.23,4.67,8.91),(3.56,9.08,7.45),(6.43,2.23,1.19),(7.89,5.32,9.08)]

fields = [StructField('a', DoubleType(),True),
          StructField('b', DoubleType(),True),
          StructField('c', DoubleType(),True)
         ]

schema = StructType(fields)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.show()

# +----+----+----+
# |   a|   b|   c|
# +----+----+----+
# |1.54|3.45|2.56|
# |9.39|8.31|1.34|
# |1.25|3.31|9.87|
# |9.35|5.67|2.49|
# |1.23|4.67|8.91|
# |3.56|9.08|7.45|
# |6.43|2.23|1.19|
# |7.89|5.32|9.08|
# +----+----+----+

#Stage 1

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['a','b','c'],outputCol='features')

df_trans = assembler.transform(df)

kmeans = KMeans(k=3, seed=123)

km_model = kmeans.fit(df_trans)

predictions = km_model.transform(df_trans)

predictions.orderBy('prediction').show()

# +----+----+----+----------------+----------+
# |   a|   b|   c|        features|prediction|
# +----+----+----+----------------+----------+
# |1.25|3.31|9.87|[1.25,3.31,9.87]|         0|
# |1.23|4.67|8.91|[1.23,4.67,8.91]|         0|
# |3.56|9.08|7.45|[3.56,9.08,7.45]|         0|
# |7.89|5.32|9.08|[7.89,5.32,9.08]|         0|
# |9.39|8.31|1.34|[9.39,8.31,1.34]|         1|
# |9.35|5.67|2.49|[9.35,5.67,2.49]|         1|
# |1.54|3.45|2.56|[1.54,3.45,2.56]|         2|
# |6.43|2.23|1.19|[6.43,2.23,1.19]|         2|
# +----+----+----+----------------+----------+

# Stage 2
bins = predictions.select("prediction").distinct().collect()

count = 0
for row in bins:
    count+=1
    #create a sub dataframe for each unique prediction and re-estimate
    sub_df = (predictions.filter(F.col('prediction')==row.prediction)
              .select(['features','prediction'])
              .withColumnRenamed('prediction','previous_prediction')
              )
    sub_model = kmeans.fit(sub_df)
    sub_predictions = sub_model.transform(sub_df)
    
    #initialize if it is the first loop iteration, otherwise merge (union) rows
    if count==1:
        updated_predictions = sub_predictions
    else:
        updated_predictions = updated_predictions.union(sub_predictions)
```

Output

```
updated_predictions.orderBy('previous_prediction').withColumnRenamed('prediction','updated_prediction').show()

# +----------------+-------------------+------------------+
# |        features|previous_prediction|updated_prediction|
# +----------------+-------------------+------------------+
# |[1.25,3.31,9.87]|                  0|                 1|
# |[1.23,4.67,8.91]|                  0|                 1|
# |[3.56,9.08,7.45]|                  0|                 0|
# |[7.89,5.32,9.08]|                  0|                 2|
# |[9.39,8.31,1.34]|                  1|                 0|
# |[9.35,5.67,2.49]|                  1|                 1|
# |[1.54,3.45,2.56]|                  2|                 0|
# |[6.43,2.23,1.19]|                  2|                 1|
# +----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```